# Android OpenCV hand gesture recognition

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv, android-ndk, video-processing

I have to make a hand gesture recognition app on Android platform using OpenCV libraries. So I have to pass the captured data from OnPreviewFrame method of android to an OpenCV function for skin color detection. I am not getting how process the raw data in OpenCV and re-encode back to the video to be stored in sd card and at the same time show in real time, the background subtracted preview to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it for normal images, put a while loop,extract frames from the videos and do same segmentation operation on each frame.

Below are two links to detect yellow color in real-time.
[Link 1](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV-Python/blob/master/Other_Examples/track_yellow_draw_line.py), [Link 2](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV-Python/blob/master/Other_Examples/single_color_multiple_points_track.py)

(Codes are in Python, and it is done for PC, not android platform. But you wouldn't have problem to understand the idea).

Comment: I am not getting how to pass live feed from the android camera to the segmentation function and then show the processed video input to the user in real time